# Group by sql query on comma joined column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My table structure is like below, **"Mail"** column can contain multiple email joined by comma

**Data(int)**

**Mail(varchar(200))**

> **[Data]**     **[Mail]**

---

> 1            m1@gmail.com,m2@hotmail.com
>
> 2                   m2@hotmail.com,m3@test.com

& I need to generate the report like below, counting each row per each email

> **[Mail]**                        **[Count]**

---

> m1@gmail.com              1
>
> m2@hotmail.com         2
>
> m3@test.com                1

So what will be the sql(server) query to generate like above? Also I can't change the table structure.

Comment: Why have you tagged this both `MySQL` and `SQL Server` I doubt that you'll get a cross platform query to do this.

Comment: I know you say you can't but if this is going to be a common requirement you need to **change the table structure**.  This would be so much easier with a normalized email list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String splitting is faster using only CHARINDEX without XML or CTE.

Sample table

```
create table #tmp ([Data] int, [Mail] varchar(200))
insert #tmp SELECT 1,'m1@gmail.com,m2@hotmail.com,other, longer@test, fifth'
UNION ALL   SELECT 2,'m2@hotmail.com,m3@test.com'
UNION ALL   SELECT 3,'m3@single.com'
UNION ALL   SELECT 4,''
UNION ALL   SELECT 5,null
```

The query

```
select single, count(*) [Count]
from
(
    select ltrim(rtrim(substring(t.mail, v.number+1,
        isnull(nullif(charindex(',',t.mail,v.number+1),0)-v.number-1,200)))) single
    from #tmp t
    inner join master..spt_values v on v.type='p'
        and v.number <= len(t.Mail)
        and (substring(t.mail,v.number,1) = ',' or v.number=0)
) X
group by single
```

The only parts you supply are

- **#tmp**: your table name
- **#mail**: the column name

Comment: I tested yours against both of the cte versions and this is three times slower (according to query plan). I only tested with your sample data and perhaps there are situations where it is faster to not use a cte. Like when there are a lot of addresses on one row (deep recursion).

Comment: @Mikael - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992419/group-by-sql-query-on-comma-joined-column/5010081#5010081

Comment: +1 According to Adam Machanic [using CLR](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/04/28/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable.aspx) is the fastest approach he links to some huge thread on SQL Server Central discussing performance of various approaches. I've not read the thread though as it is 50 pages long.

Comment: @Martin It's only 49pp.. there was no conclusive evidence that CLR was the fastest although the last few pages seem to favour the `tally method` (which is charindex splitting). I imagine CLR would be faster since the string is split in one go from left to right, but that involves installing something.

Comment: @cyberkiwi Thanks. I only looked at the query cost of the execution plan. On my computer elapsed time for your query is 37 ms against 404 ms for mine. There is a lot of parallelism going on in the query plan for your query. The cost however, (what ever that is?) is 1% for cte version against 99 % for charindex version.

Comment: @Mikael - the execution plan becomes a lie if not read properly. Anyway, link from Martin's comment is pretty good.

Comment: @cyberkiwi - 485 posts in a thread on SQLServerCentral. Well... hmm... I read that later. I'm sure it will sort everything out :). I guess you are the SQLkivi guy?

Comment: @Mik no I'm not on that thread. You may find cyberkiwi elsewhere, but not there

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - [Interesting post by SQLKiwi on the XML method here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/09/05/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

A SQL Server Solution

```
WITH T ([Data], [Mail])
     AS (SELECT 1,'m1@gmail.com,m2@hotmail.com' UNION ALL
         SELECT 2,'m2@hotmail.com,m3@test.com')
SELECT address  AS Mail,
       COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM   T
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<m>' + REPLACE([Mail], ',', '</m><m>') + '</m>'
                                AS XML
                           ) AS x) ca1
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT T.split.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS address
                    FROM   x.nodes('/m') T(split)) ca
GROUP  BY address
```

Comment: Nice trick to convert this to XML and use the inbuild functionality.  The puritan in me screams that it's abuse, and the hacker in me is just sitting smug with a banner saying "but it works..."

Comment: +1 Nice. Has some problems when ANSI settings not set correctly though `SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.`

Answer (score 2):

**SQL Server**
Using a recursive cte.

```
declare @Mail table (ID int, Mail varchar(200))

insert into @Mail values
(1, 'm1@gmail.com,m2@hotmail.com'),
(2, 'm2@hotmail.com,m3@test.com'),
(3, 'm2@hotmail.com')

;with cte1 as
(
  select Mail+',' as Mail
  from @Mail
),
cte2
as
(
  select
    left(Mail, charindex(',', Mail)-1) as Mail1,
    right(Mail, len(Mail)-charindex(',', Mail)) as Mail
  from cte1
  union all
  select
    left(Mail, charindex(',', Mail)-1) as Mail1,
    right(Mail, len(Mail)-charindex(',', Mail)) as Mail
  from cte2
  where charindex(',', Mail) > 1
)
select
  Mail1 as Mail,
  count(*) as [Count]
from cte2
group by Mail1
```

**Edit 1**
Same as before but handles the case where there is only one email in `Mail`

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Mikael's answer with minor tweaks...
- Have a field with a 'cached' LEN to avoid having to repeatedly count the length
- Use only one UNION each recursion by replacing a 0 CHARINDEX with NULL

These differences will only really show noticably for long lists, and so with several levels of recursion.

The CROSS APPLY business is just to make the SELECT more tidy, rather than repeat the NULLIF(CHARINDEX) loads of times.

```
WITH
  source (
    Data,
    Mail
  )
AS
(
  SELECT 1,'m1@gmail.com,m2@hotmail.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,'m2@hotmail.com,m3@test.com'
)
,
  split_cte
AS
(
  SELECT
    LEFT (mail, ISNULL(comma - 1, LEN(mail)))     AS "current_mail",
    RIGHT(mail, ISNULL(LEN(mail) - comma, 0))     AS "mail_data",
    ISNULL(LEN(mail) - comma, 0)                  AS "chars"
  FROM
    source
  CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', mail), 0) AS "comma") AS search

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    LEFT (mail_data, ISNULL(comma - 1, chars))    AS "current_mail",
    RIGHT(mail_data, ISNULL(chars - comma, 0))    AS "mail_data",
    ISNULL(chars - comma, 0)                      AS "chars"
  FROM
    split_cte
  CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', mail_data), 0) AS "comma") AS search
  WHERE
    chars > 0
)

SELECT
  current_mail     AS "Mail",
  COUNT(*)         AS "Count"
FROM
  split_cte
GROUP BY
  current_mail
```

Comment: Nice. I guess you mean to have `Mail` instead of `Data` in the non recursive part of the query. (Made me look at my version a second time as well :) )

Comment: Mikael's edit to concatenate a ',' at the very start is better than my NULLIF version.  Would still recommend a "length" field in the CTE of Mikael's version though.

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do would be to add a related table to store multiple emails. It is virtually always a bad design decision to store things in a comma delimited list as you have found in trying to query it. This generally means you need to create a related table as you have a one-to-many relationship. The task you want to do is trivial if you have properly related tables.

I don't buy I can't change the table structure as an excuse. Unless this is a commercial product that your company doesn't own, you can change the structure, you just need to show management why it is necessary.  Someone at your organization can change the database structure, find out who and convince him as to why it needs to change. If it is a commercial database, consider creating a trigger on the tble to populate a realted table that you create every time the email field is inserted updated or deleted. Then at least you only have to go through the splitting process once for each record change rather than every time the query is run.

Comment: Agreed, better to use this type of logic to break the list into items before inserting into the table, rather than afterwards.

Comment: "I don't buy I can't change the table structure as an excuse" does not account for company politics.  Being an employee means that certain decisions are not yours to make.  Also, changing Any stable and live environment always has a risk of un-intended consequences.  A derived table makes sense in such cases, but some people have moral objections to triggers.  The fact is, some time these things can't be changed, even if they should be.  It's the real world.  The real world is full of mess and bad decisions.

Comment: Oh, but I'm biased, mess and bad decisions by "oil tanker" like companies keeps me in work.

Comment: Triggers get bad press due to mis-use and mis-understanding.  1) Coding for INSERTs but forgetting DELETEs (and UPDATEs).  2) Many people find it counter intuititive that writign to one table causes a change in another.  3) The trigger can cause a "hidden" overhead when writing to that table.  4) The trigger could write to a table that has a trigger, greatly exaserbating point 3.

Comment: I loved pointer arithmatic in C, but I loved the reduction in memory leaks when I started playing in Java. Triggers can be viewed in the same light.  So, no, I'm not kidding.  I think triggers are powerfull and I also know that many individuals/organisations absolutely hate them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a supplementary answer to show the performance of the various options:

Fill a sample table with some data

```
create table tmp1 ([Data] int, [Mail] varchar(200))
insert tmp1 SELECT 1,'m1@gmail.com,m2@hotmail.com,other, longer@test, fifth'
UNION ALL   SELECT 2,'m2@hotmail.com,m3@test.com'
UNION ALL   SELECT 3,'m3@single.com'
UNION ALL   SELECT 4,''
UNION ALL   SELECT 5,null

insert tmp1
select data*10000 + number, mail
from tmp1, master..spt_values v
where v.type='P'

-- total rows: 10245
```

Test query:

```
set statistics io on
set statistics time on

dbcc dropcleanbuffers dbcc freeproccache

select single, count(*) [Count]
from
(
    select ltrim(rtrim(substring(t.mail, v.number+1,
        isnull(nullif(charindex(',',t.mail,v.number+1),0)-v.number-1,200)))) single
    from tmp1 t
    inner join master..spt_values v on v.type='p'
        and v.number <= len(t.Mail)
        and (substring(t.mail,v.number,1) = ',' or v.number=0)
) X
group by single

dbcc dropcleanbuffers dbcc freeproccache

;with cte1 as
(
  select Mail+',' as Mail
  from tmp1
),
cte2
as
(
  select
    left(Mail, charindex(',', Mail)-1) as Mail1,
    right(Mail, len(Mail)-charindex(',', Mail)) as Mail
  from cte1
  union all
  select
    left(Mail, charindex(',', Mail)-1) as Mail1,
    right(Mail, len(Mail)-charindex(',', Mail)) as Mail
  from cte2
  where charindex(',', Mail) > 1
)
select
  Mail1 as Mail,
  count(*) as [Count]
from cte2
group by Mail1

dbcc dropcleanbuffers dbcc freeproccache

--SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON
--SET ANSI_NULLS ON
;
SELECT address  AS Mail,
       COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM   tmp1
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<m>' + REPLACE([Mail], ',', '</m><m>') + '</m>'
                                AS XML
                           ) AS x) ca1
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT T.split.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS address
                    FROM   x.nodes('/m') T(split)) ca
GROUP  BY address
```

#### Statistics

Run a few time to get a feel for the averages

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 8196, logical reads 26637, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tmp1'. Scan count 3, logical reads 43, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 14, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 641 ms,  elapsed time = 412 ms.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 103271, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tmp1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 43, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 14, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 609 ms,  elapsed time = 614 ms.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tmp1'. Scan count 3, logical reads 43, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 14, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2798 ms,  elapsed time = 1421 ms.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 103334, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tmp1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 43, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 14, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 734 ms,  elapsed time = 742 ms.
```

#### Summary

**First (CHARINDEX)** : CPU time = 344 ms,  elapsed time = 198 ms.
**Second (CTE)** : CPU time = 594 ms,  elapsed time = 613 ms.
**Third (XML)** : CPU time = 2812 ms,  elapsed time = 1418 ms.
**Fourth (CTE2)** : CPU time = 719 ms,  elapsed time = 750 ms.