# Adding Dyanmic In() Conditions in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Facing problem for generating SQL Server Query
In the Following query dynamic conditions are added to check whether value is null or not

```
Select  * 
From    tblEmployees 
where   EmployeeName =  Case 
                            When @EmployeeName Is Not Null 
                                Then @EmployeeName 
                            Else EmployeeName 
                        End
```

But I need to add IN () Conditions and the parameter with in the IN () could be null or blank also ,if the parameter /string which is passed to the IN condition is blank then i donot want to add that condition in the query.

So how can i Achieve this.A helping hand will be very useful for me.

Thanks and Regards,
D.Mahesh

Comment: The requirements you stated is a little unclear. Can you please explain a little bit more regarding the IN clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on value of your parameter (blank of not), you can create SQL string accordingly.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(1000)
IF(ISNULL(@YourParameter,'')='')
    @sqlCommand = 'your query goes here'
ELSE
    @sqlCommand = 'your query goes here'
```

and then, run it using dynamic query execution

```
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

If not dynamic query then,

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
WHERE CASE WHEN ISNULL(@YourParameter,'')='' THEN '' ELSE EmployeeName END IN (ISNULL(@YourParameter,''))
```

See if this works...

Comment: Hi Anil,Thanks for ur response but if i donot want to create a dynamic query in that case how should i go ahead with it

Comment: Hi,thanks for ur response, I tried ur method but by following example but still not getting results  Declare @EmployeeName VARCHAR(500)
--set @EmployeeName = '''test1'',''test2'''
set @EmployeeName = '''nishap'''
--set @EmployeeName = null
--set @EmployeeName = ''

SELECT * from 
STBStg.StgUserFilter 
WHERE CASE 
WHEN ISNULL(@EmployeeName,'')='' THEN '' 
ELSE UserName END IN ( @EmployeeName  )

Comment: @Mahesh: Try removing quotes from @EmployeeName. It should be "test1, test2"

Comment: I have set the values like this Declare @EmployeeName VARCHAR(500)
set @EmployeeName = "test1,test2" and run the above query it gives me error - Invalid column name 'test1,test2'.

Comment: Otherwise, simply put IF condition and write two separate queries - one if blank and other in else part using IN clause

Comment: Hi Anil, Tried some more and got the result from the above query just used the Split function in the given query and got success  thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

I think the Dynamic query is the best solution, however you could put the *"IS NULL" and "IS BLANK"* condition in **OR** with your **IN** clause.

Something like that

```
Select  * 
From    tblEmployees 
where   @EmployeeName is null or EmployeeName in (@EmployeeName)
```

When @EmployeeName is null, your **IN** clause will be ignored

Comment: Hi ,I tried ur method but it doesnot gives me appropriate results  following is the Code which i am trying 
Declare @EmployeeName VARCHAR(500)
--set @EmployeeName = '''test1'',''test2''' for the commneted values ifts not working 
set @EmployeeName = '''nishap'''
--set @EmployeeName = null
--set @EmployeeName = ''

EXEC('Select  * 
From    STBStg.StgUserFilter 
where (' + @EmployeeName + ') is null or  
UserName in (' + @EmployeeName + ')')

Comment: @Mahesh: Seems like you are using dynamic query here. If so, why would you add the condition to the `WHERE` clause in case of NULL at all? If `@EmployeeName` is NULL, just do not add the WHERE clause, and if it is not NULL, add it simply as `'...WHERE EmployeeName IN (' + @EmployeeName + ')'`

Comment: @Mahesh: On the other hand, if you wish to avoid dynamic queries, as you commented elsewhere, then you cannot use `@EmployeeName` as a list of items inside `IN`. `@EmployeeName` can be only treated as a single string value there.

Comment: I agree with Andriy M. However if you need to use one parameter in the IN clause you have to create a procedure to split it into a list, because TSQL does not support array type variable (as far as i know).

Comment: Hi Andriy,thanks for your response as it is not possible for me to send list of items inside IN if i avoid dynamic queries i agree with u,so i would go ahead with dynamic queries but still its not taking the list of items in the dynamic query also here is the scenario  Declare @EmployeeName VARCHAR(500)
set @EmployeeName = '''nishap'',''mihir'''  EXEC('Select  * 
From    STBStg.StgUserFilter 
where filtertype = ''AccountFilter'' and  (' + @EmployeeName + ') is null or  
UserName in (' + @EmployeeName + ')') if a single value is passed it works but not for mulitple values(list of items)

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right you have `@EmployeeName = 'Name1,Name2,Name3'` and you want to get the employees that is named Name1 or Name2 or Name3, also the variable `@EmployeeName` can be `null` or contain an empty string.

Instead of using `IN` you can split the string `@EmployeeName` on `,` and store it in a table variable or temporary table. Then you can use that table in a join against `tblEmployees` to get the rows you need.

There are a lot of posts in S.O. about how to split a string. Here is one recent variant.
[Group by sql query on comma joined column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992419/group-by-sql-query-on-comma-joined-column)

This will work for SQL Server 2005 or later.

```
declare @EmployeeName varchar(100) = 'Name2,Name3,Name5'

-- Null or empty will have a comma
set @EmployeeName = coalesce(@EmployeeName, '') + ','

-- cteNames splits the string to rows
;with cteNames
as
(
  select
    left(@EmployeeName, charindex(',', @EmployeeName)-1) as Name,
    right(@EmployeeName, len(@EmployeeName)-charindex(',', @EmployeeName)) as EmployeeName
  union all
  select
    left(EmployeeName, charindex(',', EmployeeName)-1) as Name,
    right(EmployeeName, len(EmployeeName)-charindex(',', EmployeeName)) as EmployeeName
  from cteNames
  where charindex(',', EmployeeName) > 1
)
select E.*
from tblEmployees as E
  inner join cteNames as N
    on E.Name = N.Name or
       @EmployeeName = ','

-- @EmployeeName = ',' will give you all names when @EmployeeName is null of empty
```

Comment: Hi Mikael,Thanks that working great but if i need to add such 4-5 in conditions so that means i need to creat 4-5 inner joins will that not make my query slow

Comment: There is no way I can say anything about performance in your system. It depends on how much data you have in your tables and what indexes you have among etc.