# Can I avoid using cursors here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

So here is the starting point

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (  
  ID      INT IDENTITY(1,1),  
  MyData  VARCHAR(200)  
)   

INSERT INTO #Data (Data) VALUES ('Test123, Test678')  
INSERT INTO #Data (Data) VALUES ( 'abcd, efgh, mnop')
```

I want to parse comma separated data from MyData column and associate it back to related ID. So the final result will be

```
ID  ParsedData
--------------
1  Test123  
1  Test678  
2  abcd  
2  efgh  
2  mnop
```

I can do it via cursors but want to avoid it. Is there any better way of writing query for it?

Comment: Use `CROSS APPLY` and a split TVF or join onto a tally table. Examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992419/group-by-sql-query-on-comma-joined-column

Comment: Don't put comma-separated data in sql server columns in the first place.  There are few worse things you could do.

Comment: @Joel: This is some external data and that's how they are sending it to me.

Comment: @marc_s: SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Martin: I looked at the link, however not sure how that can be applied here. I can get the count of each entry however I am just not sure how to related it back to ID. If you can add some example specifically to this scenario, that will be appreciated.

Comment: Based on the fact you want to query this data as normalized relational data it should be stored as such.

Comment: @palm if you can, it will go much better for you if can split this out before inserting it into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimum way of doing this is the subject of [much controversy](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic695508-338-1.aspx?Update=1) and also depends on the length of the string, frequency of the delimiters, concurrent usage, suitability in parallel plans, whether the results will be used in a `JOIN` operation...

[Erland Sommarskog does some performance tests here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-perftest.html).

I've linked to Adam Machanic's TSQL split function below that uses a numbers table. There are a load more in the link above.

[1. Create a numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)

[2. Create a split function](http://dataeducation.com/counting-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string/)

```
SELECT ID,OutParam 
FROM #Data
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(MyData,',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to changing the input of the proc?  If so you could use a custom user-defined table type;

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SomeInfo] AS TABLE(
[Id] [int] NOT NULL, 
[SomeValue] [int] NOT NULL )
```

Define your stored proc as such;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddSomeStuff]
    @theStuff [SomeInfo] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SOMETABLE ([...columns...])
    SELECT [...columns...] from @theStuff
END
```

If you need to call it from .net you'll need to create a datatable (called table below) that matches the schema and call the stored proc as so;

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("AddSomeStuff", sqlConn) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};

var param = new SqlParameter("@theStuff", SqlDbType.Structured) {Value = table};
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What input to what procedure?

Comment: I am totally at lost how your answer helps to solve the question I have asked. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The idea is that you no longer pass comma delimited information in one variable, but rather pass the data in as table structure avoiding the whole issue of parsing to being with.

Comment: This may not be an option if you can't change the input of the proc; but if it is, I think it's the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 and up, you could avoid a cursor - but splitting this comma-separated string into something useful will always be an iterating process.

There are several approaches and stored function that split up a string and return a table of values. Using [one of those function](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=88773), you could then write something like:

```
SELECT 
d.ID, Value
FROM 
#Data AS d
CROSS APPLY
[dbo].[SplitDelimited](d.MyData, ',')
```

and you'd get an output something like:

```
ID   Value
 1   Test123
 1   Test678
 2   abcd
 2   efgh
 2   mnop
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a function like this.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/convert-a-string-array-to-tabular-data-in-sql-server/375